# Vim find and replace time hh:mm

Tags: vim, time, replace, find

I am using VIM to prepare a document.

The topic is listed after the time. As an example:
`9:45am - 11:00a TOPIC ONE`

`12:00pm - 1:20p TOPIC TWO`

I am trying to replace the times listed in the document with the word TOPIC: so that a reader can run through and scrape the topic names. But how do you do a find/replace using regex in vim?
I am familiar with:

`:%s/FIND/REPLACEWITH/g` but not how I would do this with regex. Is there a simple way to do a find replace with time formats?

It seems like a question that would have been asked before, but I cannot find how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: `FIND` in `:s/FIND/REPLACEWITH/g` _is_ a regexp (although Vim-flavour, which is rather different from the usual). `:help pattern` to learn more. Also, do you really have `am` and `pm` for the start time, but `a` and `p` for the end time?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, `:s`. `%` means "whole file". Vim regexp wants you to escape `?`, but other than that this particular regexp is as straightforward as they go:

```
:%s/^\d\d\?:\d\d[ap]m - \d\d\?:\d\d[ap]/TOPIC:/g
```